# Javascript object literal function

Tags: javascript

How can I remove quotes from a JavaScript object literal only by "function" part? For example:

Before

```
{ "a3" : { "text" : "function(a1,a2) {return a1+a2 }" }
```

After removing

```
{ "a3" : { "text" : function(a1,a2) {return a1+a2 } }
```

P.S: PHP `json_encode` puts quotes for each value. I need an object function without quotes.

Comment: Making a couple of assumptions, the correct solution is: Fix your design so that functions start out life as part of your program and are not loaded into it as part of some data. Logic and data should be separated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you trust the source of this content, you can use `eval()`

```
someVar = eval('(' + a3.text + ')');
```

Comment: eval will not work unless he adds a name to his function, and even so, it will not return the function object (I tested it)

Comment: @Deleteman It will work if he does something like `var someVar = eval('(' + a3.text + ')');`

Comment: @Bergi eval is not evil if you trust the source and the source is secure (no injection of any kind from another source)

Comment: It's not so about security, but about performance and all those scope issues. If you can avoid using it, do it. [[1](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx)]

Comment: @Bergi Javascript's eval, unlike PHP's is very fast. I don't know of it's scoping issues, I assume it just executes everything in the scope of the function you call it from. I do agree with you. Avoid using it when you can, but there are some situations where it's appropriate. Such as in Douglas Crockford's json2.js JSON parser which uses eval after a bunch of regex checks to make sure nothing non JSON get's through.

Comment: Yeah javascript eval is the fastest way to do something like this. The big problem with JS eval is security, which is why I prefaced this with "if you trust the source".

Comment: @ChrisSobolewski You also have to wrap parenthesis around the a3.text see my comment to Deleteman and this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A4VPe/2/

Comment: Actually I added them in for you to make your post work since you seem to have gone offline.

Comment: ha, thanks, I was in the process of editting when yours went through.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a javascript Object literal, just write / `echo`

```
{ "a3" : { "text" : function(a1,a2) {return a1+a2 } }
```

If you have a JSON string, bear in mind that JSON does not know functions. PHP's `json_encode` behaviour is only correct.